# Unit testing atomic library functions

Tags: c, multithreading, unit-testing, atomic, testcase

How would one go about unit testing an atomic function that is part of an API?  How can you guarantee that the atomicity of the function is actually being tested in time dependent situations like this? The system I am working with is inherently multithreaded with many real-time elements, and is written in C.

My first thought is to perhaps set up one or more threads that are set to try and modify the same data that the atomic function under test is operating on, then check to see if the resultant value of the data is different than expected. Is this a valid approach? Or am I missing an obvious solution to the problem?

Comment: Not unit-testable by definition, sorry.

Comment: You can't unit test this as SergeyA stated. You can test the inputs passed into the API by creating stubs for those functions, but you can't actually test what the API is doing.

Comment: You can only give a test that proves that the implementation is incorrect, never that it is correct. Something like having a lot of threads hammer on the same variable with an atomic increment. At the end you should be able to see if the total number of increments is correct. And you should test that with different optimization levels, the code that is choosen for this kind of operation depends a lot on that.

Comment: Is there any way at all to test atomicity?